# send mail when user click on button in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, email

i have one view page for candidates..so in that i gave one button for REQUEST CONTACT INFO..so when user click on this button i need to send mail..

When user click on button i just gave one popup like your request is confirmed..then user will click on ok...then poup will closed..

Here is my button code:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="getConfirmation();"><b>REQUEST CONTACT INFO</b></button></td>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function getConfirmation(){
           var retVal = confirm("your request is confiremed ?");
</script>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function user_view_candidates()

{ 

    $data['view_candidates'] = $this->CandidateModel->getcandidates();
    $this->load->view('Candidates/user-view-candidates',$data);
}
```

Can anyone help me how to do this..i know how to send mail..

I want to know when user click button how to send mail..

Can anyone help me..

Comment: you need to fire an ajax on confirmation and the url of  the ajax would be the function where u use the mail function.

Comment: can you please explain in code..how to write ajax function for that one..i don't have that much of knowledge on ajax..

Comment: u can do like- `function getConfirmation(){
           var retVal = confirm("your request is confiremed ?");
     if(retVal){
$.ajax({
url:'tothemailfunction',
success:function(data){

}
});

}
`
do u know how to pass url in codeignitor?

Comment: can i write mail funtion  directly   in controller

Comment: this would be in your view page in script tag and you also have to include the jquery in your view page like this just copy and paste this-`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script>

    function getConfirmation(){ var retVal = confirm("your request is confiremed ?"); if(retVal){ $.ajax({ url:'tothemailfunction', success:function(data){ } }); } `
</script>`

Comment: wow..its working..but i have another problem every time when i refresh the page ..mail will send..how to prevent this..

Comment: .r u using putting the mail function in this function `user_view_candidates`

Comment: yes..i put mail function inside user_view_candidates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function getConfirmation(){
    var retVal = confirm("your request is confiremed ?");
    if(retVal) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'tothemailfunction',
            success:function(data){
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: u have to make the separate function for mailing and then on ajax url u need to pass the url to that function. do u know how to pass the url?

Comment: okay then give me the url of ur current page and the name of the new function that you will create to send the mail.